# Bind variable not set error- passing array to snowflake SQL stored procedure

Tags: c#, arrays, stored-procedures, parameters, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

While passing an array parameter to a Snowflake stored procedure from my .NET layer, I get an exception:

> Error: SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 58\nBind variable :P_ID not set. SqlState: 42601, VendorCode: 2049, QueryId: XXXXX

Below is the code I have tried:

```
public static void DemoArray()
{
    string sp = "CALL DBNAME.SCHEMANAME.ARRAY_STOREDPROC_NAME(:P_ID)"; 

    try
    {
        using (IDbConnection snowflakeDbConnection = GetDbConnection(SnowflakeOperationsConnectionString, RSA_Key_Location))
        {
            using (IDbCommand cmd = snowflakeDbConnection.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = sp;

                List<int> array = new List<int>();
                array.Add(1011);
                array.Add(1022);

                var p1 = cmd.CreateParameter();
                p1.ParameterName = "P_ID";
                p1.DbType = DbType.Int32;                       
                p1.Value = array.ToArray();
                cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);                     

                var readerResult = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            }                   
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        throw exception;
    }
}
    
public static IDbConnection GetDbConnection(string snowflakeConnectionString, string RSA_Key_Location)
{
    IDbConnection snowflakeDbConnection = new SnowflakeDbConnection();
    snowflakeDbConnection.ConnectionString = snowflakeConnectionString + " private_key_file =" + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString() + RSA_Key_Location;

    snowflakeDbConnection.Open();

    return snowflakeDbConnection;
}
```

Comment: Instead of names parameter can you try like below
https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-net#bind-array-variables